# How to create a new view with the AddButton in the Master-Detail Application

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, storyboard

I've made a Master-Detail Application with Xcode. 
No I have following problem / question.

If you press on top on the "ADD" Button, I want to create a new view. I found out how it works programmatically.

```
UIViewController *addView = [[UIViewController alloc]init];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:addView animated:YES];
```

But the new View doesn't exist in the storyboard editor now. Do I have to create labels, textFields and so on programmatically also? Or is there another way to do this.

Greets

Answer (score 0):

Views created programatically do not show up on the storyboard.

If it is just a one-off view that you want to create, you can add it to the storyboard, set all the properties and subviews, set it to `hidden` and bind it to an ivar. That way you can access it through the ivar and just set `hidden` to `no` when you want to show it. There are other ways you could try, but this is nice and easy.

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer. 
Could you bring an example. I'm completely new in this topic.

Answer (score 0):

Storyboard views and programatically created views can co-exist quite nicely. If you need them ithe storyobard, for whatever reason, then create the view there and hide (and deactivate) it from start. In the program instead of creating a new one just unhide it and activate it.

However, there is no reason not to create it programmatically.

With the storyboard it works in principle like this: 
Each view has a correspoinding `nib` file in `XML` format, `xib` called. When a view is loaded this XML file is loaded. All the views and the settings you made in IB/Storyboard are stored there in XML format. Then the framework works through the entries in the `XML` file and creates the views programmatically for you by usint the settings from the `xml` file.

So in the end, a view that has been created programmatically is not much different from a view created through a storyboard.

For programmatically created views:

- You don't need a property.
- If you need one, it does not need to be marked as `IBOutlet`.
- A property of a programmatically created view
  should be `strong`. IB/Storyboard `IBOutlet` view properties can be `weak`.
- The storyboard does not 'know' them. Therefore you cannot link segues
  within the stoyboard to the related actions etc. But you can invoke
  segues programmaticaly to and the storyboard will continue running.